# Is there any way to convert a float into an int without losing the decimal values?

Tags: c++, floating-point, int, type-conversion

I'm trying to convert a float value to an integer, modify the int value, then reconvert back to a float value. However, the decimals' value gets lost and I'm pretty sure I used the **static_cast<>()** function wrong in my code.

My code is a binary multiplier, which shifts the binary value *f* times to left. For example, when I'm doing something like 1.2 x 2, I'm only getting 2 instead of 2.4.

```
int mantissa;
int f;
int exp;
float result = mantissa + 0x800000;
int resultInt = static_cast<int>(result);
int expF = log2(abs(f));
int expM = exp + expF;
int newExp = (127 + 23 - expM);
resultInt >>= newExp;
float result2 = resultInt;
```

Comment: Why not just save the integer representation of the float value to another variable? Then you would preserve the original and still have the int value that you want.

Comment: Multiply with a certain factor to get a fixed decimal `int` representation.

Comment: Why convert to an int at all? If you want a float, keep it as a float.

Comment: I'd start by cracking open a dictionary and looking up what the word "integer" means.

Comment: @WilliamKappler Yes, but in order to shift position the variable resultInt must be an integer.

Comment: What are you trying to do? (So what is the name of the function that contains this code?) Multiplying two floats faster than by doing `f1 * f2`? In that case you should not even think about logarithms.

Comment: You start out with three uninitialized variables, and then add `0x80000000` ?? How is this even remotely supposed to work?

Comment: @MSalters: with magic, of course. Programming is nothing else.

Comment: @student That doesn't really explain why any of this is being done in the first place. Mind you, I don't consider myself an expert in binary operations, but this looks like a Rube Goldberg. I'd it be however many FLOPs the compiler makes it, rather than try to do better yourself. You won't do better.

Comment: It might be that you are looking to use a "union". https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/union

Answer (score 3):

Bit shifting will not work for floating point values because the bits are laid out differently. They have to preserve the decimal location as well as the digits (hence the floating "point" value).

An integer, on the other hand, works well with bit shifting due to how well it maps from decimal-to-binary, but does not store a decimal point anywhere. Thus, when casting, you lose that information.

In short, it is impossible to multiply a decimal value directly using bit shifting the same way you can with an integer.

However, you can multiply the floating point by 10 until all digits are on the left side of the decimal, then cast to an integer. It may eat up performance depending on how it's implemented, but it's certainly possible to preserve all information this way. It's difficult to answer the question beyond that without understanding your intentions.